# SharePoint 2013 - which library to use for impersonation

Tags: windows-authentication, impersonation

I am a .NET developer and a novice in the SharePoint classes available.
The SharePoint site is 2013 with a potential upgrade in its future to either SharePoint 2016 or SharePoint online.

I need my SharePoint library to interact with existing data to ease user experience.  Discovered the client context classes and found exactly what was needed to interact with our data then update the properties of a document library item.

This worked perfectly when tested from a console application.  Satisfied I moved that work into a class and started on an intranet site.  In development from my machine on localhost everything is still working fabulously.

Moved work to an intranet site and I'm not longer recognized by SharePoint in spite of the windows authentication.   Thinking I need to somehow attach impersonation of the windows user to the client context - I am overwhelmed with the large variety of libraries without much detail as to which SharePoint these libraries apply to.

I'm thinking the SPContext is for an older version of SharePoint than 2013 and that the new Oath Identity Tokens apply to the online SharePoint.  Can anyone recommend the best starting point to get my users recognized on an intranet site?  The differences between these methodologies (high trust/low trust) is overwhelming.  Since all contain a huge learning curve - I'd like to make the right choice.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - my code stopped working on the intranet site due to the identity on the application pool associated with the IIS site.

It worked locally in development because the site is running as me and I have permissions in the Sharepoint libraries.

I created an AD Account to serve as the identity on the application pool - and then added that new identity to Sharepoint libraries.

No need for impersonation.